# Android app crashes when rotated twice in image view for high quality images from gallery

Tags: android, image, rotation

1. There is no problem with low quality images i.e. less than 300 KB
2. There is no problem with single +90, 180 or 270 degrees of rotation.
3. Only if high quality images are rotated in image view for more than two times app crashes

   ```
   private void setupListeners() {

   rotateLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           *imageBitmap = Util.ImageProcess.rotateImage(imageBitmap, 270);*

           showImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

       }
   });

   rotateRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           imageBitmap = Util.ImageProcess.rotateImage(imageBitmap, 90);

           showImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

       }
   });

   flip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           imageBitmap = Util.ImageProcess.rotateImage(imageBitmap, 180);

           showImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

       }
   });

   continueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           saveRotatedImage();

           Util.MediaScanner.galleryAddPic(getApplicationContext(),imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
           startNextActivity();
       }
   });
   ```

   }

Also, for rotation :

```
public static class ImageProcess{

    public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        try {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(),
                source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
```

Comment: What exception are seeing -- OutOfMemoryError?

Answer (score 1):

Add a property in your manifest file in the application tag to allow largeheap=true that might help give it a try.

Comment: My current minimum API is 8. And I can only use it in above 11

Comment: Then other way to get that work is by scaling down the images before you use them.

Comment: Yes I did the same. By getting the ratio of the image and scaled it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution.
And the code is :

```
   int imageHeight = imageBitmap.getHeight();

    int imageWidth = imageBitmap.getWidth();

    int newImageheight;

    int newImageWidth;

    if (imageHeight <= imageWidth){

        newImageWidth = 1200;
        //getting the length and setting it 1200

        newImageheight = (1200*imageWidth)/imageHeight;
        //getting image ratio and multiplying it by the length which
        //gives width              

    }

    else {
        newImageheight = 1200;

        newImageWidth = (1200*imageHeight)/imageWidth;

    }

   imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap,
        newImageheight, newImageWidth, false);
    //setting the new scaled image in lower quality
```

This prevents the  OutOfMemoryError .